# share the same categories and sub categories in a wordpress multi languages site

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I'm trying to create a multi langueges wordpress web site (2 languages) and i need to make a link between the categories and sub categories so the user in the site1 can find the articles that were posted in the site2 and vice versa.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i've tried two multi-languages plugins but it was not what i'm looking for because i've translated all my pages manually before.

Comment: Well I meant what code have you tried so far. Can you explain more in depth? It's not clear what you're trying to do. Is this in a multisite?